# using class in <li> and <ul>

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I use Microsoft sharepoint to make a website for my organization. And when I tried to CSS-coding in `<li>` and `<ul>` it messed up my page, because microsoft also uses `<li>` and `<ul>` and my css-coding affects those too. So I have to assign a class for my `<li>` and `<ul>`. And I began with calling my `<ul class="a">` and then used this CSS-coding:

```
ul.a {list-style: none;padding: 0px;margin: 0px;}
ul.a li {display: block;position: relative;float: left;border:0px solid #000}
li ul {display: none;border:0px}
ul.a li a {display: block;background: #fff;padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;text-decoration: none;
       white-space: nowrap;color: #000;border:0px; font-family: "Courier New", Times, serif;font-size: 13px;} 
ul.a li a:hover {background: #fff;}
li:hover ul.a {display: block; position: absolute;}
li:hover li {float: none;}
li:hover a {background: #ffffff;border:0px solid #000;}
li:hover li a:hover {background: #0066ff;;border:1px solid #000;color: #fff;text-decoration: none;}
#drop-nav li ul li {border-top: 0px;}
```

But when I try to edit this line from

```
 li ul {display: none;border:0px}
```

to this

```
 li ul.a {display: none;border:0px}
```

it wont work. Why?
Becasue of this all other `<ul>`-s disappear from the page.

EDIT2:
I wrote `<il>` but did mean `<li>`

```
<style>

.menu ul {list-style: none;padding: 0px;margin: 0px;}
.menu ul li {display: block;position: relative;float:left;border:0px solid #000}
.menu li ul {display: none;border:0px}
.menu ul li a {display: block;background: #fff;padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;text-decoration: none;
       white-space: nowrap;color: #000;border:0px; font-family: "Courier New", Times, serif;font-size: 13px;} 
.menu ul li a:hover {background: #fff;}
.menu li:hover ul {display: block; position: absolute;}
.menu li:hover li {float: none;}
.menu li:hover a {background: #ffffff;border:0px solid #000;}
.menu li:hover li a:hover {background: #0066ff;;border:1px solid #000;color: #fff;text-decoration: none;}
  #drop-nav li ul li {border-top: 0px;}

</style>


<ul id="drop-nav" class="menu">
<li class="menu">
    <a title="Hjem" href="home.aspx"><img alt="HOme" src="Home.png" style="margin: 5px;" / width="53px" class="menypic"></a>
</li>
```

Now it seems like somethings not working. The menu is working, but I get this black dot right next to the picture. It should display none?

Comment: Post a complete code example please. Also, there's no `il` element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the line to this:

```
ul.menu li {display: block;position: relative;float:left;border:0px solid #000;list-style-type: none;}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define a class and put it on your ul object.

```
.list {}
.list li {}
```

Like this http://jsfiddle.net/ecro5d4f/

Sorry for the formatting. Mobile.

Edit:

```
 li ul {display: none;border:0px}
```

This might be the problem. For everything else you have a class name but this is generic.

Comment: Heh... Some editing has been done on the post in the meantime.

Comment: It's probably the default li dot. You could try adding "list-style-type: none;" in the li class.

Comment: the problem is this line:   .menu ul li {display: block;position: relative;float:left;border:0px solid #000;}

Comment: its like it dont affects the <ul> and <li>

Comment: Try replacing it with this  .menu ul li {display: block;position: relative;float:left;border:0px solid #000;list-style-type: none;}  and the dot should disappear. If this doesn't work I'll come back with an answer in the morning. It's 00:30 here and I need to sleep :).

Comment: it did not work, and if i have many dots they all come under eachother. Again it seems like this css-line dont affects the HTML-code?!

Comment: I can't test the hover because I'm on mobile but you can have a look at this  http://jsfiddle.net/7q4bo4hw/

Answer (score 0):

I tried this based on Lidaranis code and it worked: https://jsfiddle.net/ecro5d4f/1/

Is that what you looking for?

The "menu" class is an `<ul>` too, so you have to put a `list-style: none;` on it too.

```
   .menu { list-style: none;}
```